# How to pass Selenium WebDriver instances between functions in Python?

Tags: python, function, selenium, webdriver

I have a function that handles logging into a website. I then return the webdriver instance so that I can pass it into another fucnction that actually handles getting the information that I need.

For some reason I have been unable to call my second function using the returned driver instance.

Was wondering if anyone had any insight into how I can pass a webdriver instance to another function? Thanks.

Comment: "For some reason I have been unable to call my second function using the returned driver instance." Why not?

Comment: @SuperStew I receive an error that stops me from executing the processes in the second function

Comment: You're gonna need to post some of your code and the error

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

> how I can pass a webdriver instance to another function?

You would return the instance from the first function and call the second function with it.

In the example below, I define 2 functions.  A webdriver is instantiaterd inside `func1`, which returns the instance.  Then I call `func2`, which takes a driver instance as an argument.

```
from selenium import webdriver

def func1():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://example.com')
    return driver

def func2(driver):
    return driver.title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = func1()
    title = func2(driver)
    print(title)
    driver.quit()
```

This code will launch a browser (Chrome), navigate to a site (https://example.com), print the page title ("Example Domain"), and then quit the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, extending Corey Goldberg's answer. It is perfectly fine to simply pass a reference of the driver to all functions that use it.

```python
from selenium import webdriver

def func1(driver):
    driver.get('https://example.com')

def func2(driver):
    return driver.title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    func1(driver)
    title = func2(driver)
    print(title)
    driver.quit()
```